# using textAppearance in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose

Can I still use the TextAppearance stuff in Jetpack compose without much calisthenics? Example `textAppearanceHeadline1`. How do I do that? I am trying to create a Text view and make it title. But I don't want to specify an actual dp value. So I was hoping to use the usual textAppearanceHeadline1 or such.

Comment: Use style property in Text this way -->
Text(style = MaterialTheme.typography.h4)

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can help you

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalUnitApi::class)
val textAppearanceHeadline1 = Typography(
    h1 = TextStyle(
        fontFamily = FontFamily.SansSerif,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Light,
        fontStyle = FontStyle.Normal,
        fontSize = TextUnit(96f, TextUnitType.Sp),
        lineHeight = TextUnit(-0.015625f, TextUnitType.Unspecified),
    )
)
```

And in your Text

```
Text(text = "Text", style = textAppearanceHeadline1.h1)
```